# From ios simulation to ios device with xcode 4.6

Tags: ios

I have finished a small iPad simulation program with Xcode 4.6, and now I want to try this program on real iPad device. What steps should I follow? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Just make the Development certificate on apple site Then Download it.`

`Make the Development Provisioning Profile & make sure that your Profile must contain the device Id on which you want to debug the app.`

`Download your provisioning Profile. & give the certificate & profile in Build Setting`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to have an apple developper acount for that, 
i think this tutorial can help you forward how to generate all the necesarry certificates:
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/xcode-4-deploying-your-app-to-your-own-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch/